# Solution to quadratic and cubic equation with partial root

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, cubics

I am having trouble understanding how to resolve quadratic and cubic equations using the method described by my university lecturer (I am really interested to know if this method has a name). My calculator gives very different answers to what my lecturer explained and this enquiring mind wants to know why.
[image: Calculator answer]
The question was
$$x^3+8x^2+16x+3=0$$
A given root was $x=-3$

While my lecturer gives the roots $x_{1,2,3}=1,5,1$.
I'm not fully confident nor conversant with the methodology he employed yet. The general formula need not be related but the steps were something like the following:
$$x^3+8x^2+16x+3=0$$
Where $0=(x+3)(ax^2+bx+c)$ we substitute the original formula values so, expanding the equation to
$$
x^3+8x^2+16x+3=(x+3)(ax^2+bx+c)
$$
And hence expansion to
$$
=>ax^3+3ax^2+bx^2+3bx+cx+3c
$$

Since the first factor is given as $(x+3)$ we need only find the others using any other factorisation method for quadratic equations.

This is where I got very lost.
$$=ax^3+(3a+b)x^2+(3b+c)x+3c$$
By inspection a=1 and c=1 calculated by
$$a: ax^3=x^3$$
$$a: a=1$$

$$b: (3a+b)x^2=8x^2$$
$$b: 3(1)+b=8$$
$$b: b=8-3=5$$

$$c: 3=3c$$
$$c: 1=c$$

So the final factors he explained were $(x+3)(x-1)(x-5)=0$

Is this the correct final answer or is the calculator doing something not explained to me?

Edit: @Gnumbertester states that the roots found are the quadratic equation values of $(x+3)(x^2+5x+1)$
[image: graph of equation on my calculator]
I how this image helps other understand why there are 3 roots.

Fortunately I passed my degree module 1st class! Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: What's a "partial root"?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician so you'll have to correct me where the terminology is invalid.

Comment: This is wrong.  It's obvious that $x^3+8x^2+16x+3$ has no positive roots.  (If you substitute a positive number for $x,$ each term is positive.)  In fact, $x^3+8x^2+16x+3=(x+3)(x^2+5x+1)$

Comment: Reading through the discussion you provided, your instructor's _own method_ gives the quadratic polynomial as $ \ x^2 + 5x + 1 \ , $ which for whatever reason they appear promptly to forget.  The factors $ \ (x-1)·(x-5) \ $ have the product $ \ x^2 - 6x + 5 \ $ and the product   $ \ (x+3)·(x-1)·(x-5) \ = \ x^3 - 3x^2 - 13x + 15 \ $ is not the cubic polynomial in the original problem.  Someone here lost track of what they were doing...  (The results on the calculator display _are_ correct.)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is incorrect and there is a much simpler way of finding the roots.

Since you are given a root of this cubic, you can use synthetic division to reduce it to a quadratic.

You may already know how to do synthetic division, however if you don't, you can see how to do it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZoMz1Cy1T4).

Once you divide $x^3+8x^2+16x+3$ by the linear factor you are given, you are left with $x^2+5x+1$.

To find the other two roots, use the quadratic formula.

Addendum: If you are familiar with traditional, polynomial long division, that works too.

Comment: What is a linear factor?

Comment: Since you are given the root $x=-3$, you know that $x+3$ is a factor of the cubic. I just included linear because it is a linear term (degree of 1).

Comment: Above my pay grade buddy...

Comment: Linear isn't technically necessary for the understanding of this problem. The most important part is knowing that if you are given a factor of a cubic, you can find an expression (quadratic) by dividing the cubic by that factor. From there, all you need to do is factor the quadratic and you have all 3 roots of the original cubic.

Comment: You lost me at linear...

Comment: After completing my engineering mathematics module, I passed with 1st class {honours} degree. Thanks guys!